# Compact Finite Differences for the Heat Equation with Robin Boundary Conditions

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, boundary-conditions, numerical-modelling, diffusion

I am trying to solve the Heat equation with Robin Boundary condition:

$$ u_t(x,t) = u_{xx}(x,t), \\ u(x,0) = g(x), \\ u(0,t) + u_x(0,t) = h_0(t), \\ u(1,t) + u_x(1,t) = h_1(t)$$

for $ 0\leq x\leq1$ and $t>0$, by using twice the composition of a fourth-order compact finite difference (CFD) approximation of the first derivative (taken from *S. Lele (1991)*) for the spatial discretization, i.e.

$$ M \; \partial_x \textbf{u} = A \;\textbf{u} \\ M \; \partial^2_x \textbf{u} = A \; \partial_x \textbf{u}, $$

where $M, A$ are two sparse matrices, corresponding to the coefficients obtained from the CFD scheme. This would simplify as follows

$$ \partial^2_x \textbf{u} = (M^{-1} A)^2 \;\textbf{u}. $$

As adviced in *S. Lele (1991)*, I use an upwinding and downwinding scheme at the boundaries, so I avoid using ghost cells with the derivatives.

I am aware this could be done in an easier manner by using an approximation of the second derivative, as done in *J. Malele et al. (2022)*, but my problem is in fact more complicated than the one shown here and requires me to use twice the composition of the first derivative.

And here, my question: **How could I include the Robin boundary conditions?**

---

I was advised to include the equations as additional lines on the last system, so that

$$ \hat{\textbf{u}} = \begin{bmatrix} u_x\Big|_1 \\ u_0 \\ u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_N \\ u_x\Big|_{N-1} \end{bmatrix} $$

would be my new unknown, however, that makes a new matrix appear on the left hand side of the equation, i.e. left-multiplying $ \partial_x^2 \hat{\textbf{u}} $, which is a singular matrix. The fact that this is a singular matrix would then complicate the resolution of the ODE with another method time integrator.

Thank you for your time.

---

P.S.: The matrix $M$ is the matrix of coefficients of the derivatives. That means that if the schemes are of this form (as per *S. Lele (1991)*):

$$ \alpha f_{i-1}' + f_i + \alpha f_{i+1}' = \frac{a}{2h} \left( f_{i+1} - f_{i+1} \right)  \quad \forall i = 1,2,\dots, N-1$$

at the inner nodes and

$$ f_0' + \beta f_1' = \frac{1}{h}\left( bf_0 + cf_1 +df_2 + ef_3 \right) $$

at the left boundary, i.e. $i = 0$, and something similar for the right boundary, then the Matrix of coeffients will be:

$$ M := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \beta & 0 & 0 & \dots \\ \alpha & 1 & \alpha & 0 & \ddots \\ 0 & \alpha & 1 & \alpha & \ddots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \end{bmatrix} $$